# Jupyther Shift-Tab not working with Pandas

Tags: jupyter-notebook, documentation-generation

Consider executing the following conde:

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3]})

Then putting the cursor inside the parenthesis of df.sort() and hitting shift-tab does not open the documents.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda and Jupyter. Still the same problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm also experiencing it. Python3 (ipykernel) with Anaconda navigator 2.4.3 with (intentionally downgraded) 6.5.2 of Jupyter notebook (6.5.4 doesn't work either).